# Using helpers in a Lerna monorepo

Tags: javascript, babeljs, lerna, monorepo

I have a Lerna powered monorepo which contains various packages that are published to NPM. Within this have various helper functions that live on the root of the repo and are shared by a few packages.

The issue I have is that when each package is built with Babel, the transpiled code uses `require` to get those helpers. Obviously this doesn't work as when a package is published it needs to be completely self contained - those helpers are not there.

Is there a way to solve this? I don't want to have to duplicate helpers between packages.

When using `lerna bootstrap --hoist` I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest solution i see is to create an helper workspace that you do not publish when using lerna publish.

You will be able to set this "helper" workspace as a dependency of each of your workspace, therefore avoiding code duplication.